# How to select list of VALUES in redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

The following query works in Postgresql but not in Redshift:

```
WITH bar (baz) AS
    (VALUES ('a'), ('b'), ('c'))
SELECT * from bar;
```

Which gives

```
baz
---
a
b
c
```

How can I replicate this behaviour in Redshift?

Comment: create a table and insert the values first. then use that table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

unfortunately UNION is the only way here:

```
WITH bar (baz) AS
(select 'a' union select 'b' union select 'c')
SELECT * from bar;
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` is preferred here because it will be faster;  you don't want it to check for duplicates.

Comment: yeah I know it's faster and I always use UNION ALL when selecting from the tables that are supposed to have unique values but I don't think this effect would be tangible on a hardcoded list of values until you reach a certain amount

Comment: Sure no effect with a small dataset, but always good to promote best practices to people looking and learning from your examples. In spite of SQL being a set-based language I find I usually want `UNION ALL` unless I am explicitly trying to deduplicate.

Answer (score 0):

this is also a good option, IF you do NOT want to use 'WITH' option.

```
select C1, C2, C3 from  
(select '2021-10-01' as C1 , '2021-12-31' as C2 , 'Q4' as c3
union all
select '2021-01-01'  , '2021-03-31' , 'Q1' 
)
```